# Rust mutable value vs mutable reference

Tags: reference, rust, mutable

What is the difference between

```
let y = &mut 5;
*y += 1;
let x = *y + 1;
```

and

```
let mut y = 5;
y += 1;
let x = y + 1;
```

They return the same result via `println!`, but I can't decide which one is preferable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Given your simple example of binding a variable to one or the other, then calling `println!` locally, there really isn't much difference in the result (as you've noted).

A mutable value vs a mutable reference becomes more clear when you cross function boundaries. Have a look at this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = &mut 5;

    do_work(x);

    println!("{}", x);
}

fn do_work(n: &mut u32) {
    *n += 5;
}
```

What do you think it prints? [Here it is on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9401bad045be30e8d8a8b9cb0246fff1&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Now look at this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;

    do_work(x);

    println!("{}", x);
}

fn do_work(mut n: u32) {
    n += 5;
}
```

What do you think this prints? [Here it is on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=88049b740c4ef74e54fd23bcbb4bbd49&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The answers are:

The top code block prints `10`. The bottom code block prints `5`.

Using the mutable reference means you're referencing the place in memory where the variable `x` is stored. Across function boundaries, you're able to change the value stored in memory there. When the method returns and `println!` hits.. the value of `x` is updated.

In this specific example, `x` is a `u32`, which implements the `Copy` trait. When you pass `x` into the `do_work` method, a copy of `x` is made. In the body of the `do_work` method, `n += 5` adds 5 *to the copy* .. and does not reference the original block of memory at all.

> ...can't decide which one is preferable.

That depends entirely on use-case. Do you need to reference the original memory when crossing a function boundary? If you have marked your variable as mutable, there is a high chance that you do want to reference the original memory in the hopes of updating it. In that case, you would use a mutable reference. If you're just mutating a variable locally within a function.. then you won't require a reference.

Comment: You can remove the `mut` from `let mut` in the first example and it would still work, so I don't think this really answers OP's question.